# Best answer for "feel free to ..."

Tags: colloquial-language, responses

When people say "feel free to contact me", I don't know how to answer.

How do you reply this?

Comment: What do you want to answer? You don't have to answer. You could say "Thanks", "ok, I'll do", etc. But that depends on what you want to convey.

Comment: There could be a dozen way to answer this. Primarily opinion based. I'll reply *Sure!*

Answer (score 2):

> "Feel free to contact me."

This is a very polite phrase. It means that the person speaking is going out of his or her way to tell you that they are available to speak with if you want to.

Assuming you wish to be positive and you do not need additional information from them, I would suggest smiling and saying:

> "Okay. I will. Thank you (very much)."

The phrase I suggest acknowledges that you understand what they said, that they made a polite gesture and that the offer is being politely accepted.

If you want a less committed answer (perhaps you may not contact them) you can say:

> "I appreciate that. Thank you."

or simply

> "Thank you (very much)".

This still tells them that you understand what they said and that they are being politely acknowledged, but doesn't give as much of an expectation you will contact them as "Okay. I will. Thank you."

Finally, there are a lot more ways to reply to this phrase, but all of them involve acknowledging you understand what has been said politely. These phrases can include:

- "Okay."
- "Sure."
- "All right."
- "Thanks."
- "Can do"/ "Will do" ("I can do that", "I will do that" -- both are very informal)